# Could not find a production build in the '/opt/app/.next' directory

Tags: reactjs, docker, next.js

#### What version of Next.js are you using?

10.0.5

#### What version of Node.js are you using?

14 alpine

#### What browser are you using?

Chrome

#### What operating system are you using?

Windows

#### How are you deploying your application?

next build in Dockerfile

#### Describe the Bug

My next build & next start was working fine. Suddenly without any change i am getting this error during runtime

> **Could not find a production build in the '/opt/app/.next' directory**

Here is my docker file

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN chown -R node:node /opt/app

USER node

ARG NPM_TOKEN
RUN echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN" > .npmrc

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY --chown=node:node . /opt/app

RUN npm install --dev && npm run lint && npm run build:app

RUN ls -la

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

EXPOSE 3000
```

here is my package.json scripts

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./bin/start.js",
"build:app": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production rm -rf .next && APP_TENANT_CODE=app && next build",
```

here is my start.js file

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
/**
 * So next.config.js doesn't allow async functions, but we need to read
 * runtime config variables from Key Vault.
 *
 * So instead we will read them and then start next.js server in  custom script.
 *
 */
const path = require('path')
const { default: startServer } = require('next/dist/server/lib/start-server')

process.on('SIGTERM', () => process.exit(0))
process.on('SIGINT', () => process.exit(0))

async function main() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
  const dir = path.resolve(__dirname, '..')
  const hostname = '0.0.0.0'

  // start the app
  const app = await startServer({ dir }, port, hostname)
  console.log(`started server on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
  await app.prepare()
}

main().catch(error => console.error(error))
```

after running docker image i am getting this error

```
Error: Could not find a production build in the '/opt/app/.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server. https://err.sh/vercel/next.js/production-start-no-build-id
    at Server.readBuildId (/opt/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:146:355)
    at new Server (/opt/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:3:120)
    at createServer (/opt/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:2:638)
    at start (/opt/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:1:323)
    at main (/opt/app/bin/start.js:52:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/app/bin/start.js:57:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
```

.

#### Expected Behavior

application should start on http://127.0.0.1:3000

#### To Reproduce

use Dockerfile and start.js file as mentioned above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your .next directory is empty when you create the container from that image.

update the docker file accordingly.

```
FROM node:16
WORKDIR /opt/app

RUN chown -R node:node /opt/app
USER node

ARG NPM_TOKEN
RUN echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN" > .npmrc

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . /opt/app
RUN npm run lint

RUN npm run build:fair
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]

EXPOSE 3000
```